# How to ignore hosts file?

Tags: browser, hosts

I need to know if there is a web browser using its own "hosts" file or simply ignoring the "hosts" file from OS.

**UPDATE 1**: This is the situation:

- certain program requires certain URL for validation : not wanted
- I need that URL for getting help : wanted

I tested with Firefox, Chromium, Vivaldi, Midori, and all of them read *hosts* file.

Comment: Could you be more specific on context of the why(s) of this question?

Comment: @Christopher You should write that up as an answer.

Comment: Making a web browser ignore the `hosts` file might not solve your problem. My guess is that access to external network (or just to that specific URL) is blocked by an external firewall, and the `hosts` entry exists just to make those requests fail without waiting for a TCP connection to time out, which would cause an annoying delay.

Comment: I think i found one possible solution, please check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know if there is browser based utility to do this. But you can do it for the entire OS. The key file is `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. To support only DNS records you should have record inside like:

```
hosts: DNS
```

if you need to have `/etc/hosts` and the file have precedence over DNS you need to have record like:

```
hosts: files DNS
```

**EDIT**: You can set Firefox to use DNS over https. [Here](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/software/mozilla-firefox-expands-dns-over-https-doh-test-to-release-channel/) you can find detailed instructions:

> Type `about:config` in the Firefox address bar and then press enter. When Firefox asks, click on the button stating that you accept the
>   risks.
>   In the search field enter `network.trr` to display all of the settings for Firefox's Trusted Recursive Resolver, which is the
>   DNS-over-HTTPS Endpoint used by Firefox.
>   Double-click on `network.trr.mode`, enter 2 in the field, and press OK as shown below. This turns on DoH in Firefox.
>   Next you need to make sure the `network.trr.uri` is set to https://mozilla.cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query as this is Cloudflare's
>   DoH DNS resolver that Firefox has partnered with for the test. If it
>   is not set to this URL, please double-click on the setting and enter
>   the URL.
>   You can now close the `about:config` page.